# Check if key exists in memcache cluster using PHP

Tags: php, memcached

I'm debugging the caching layer of a PHP application. It uses a cluster of memcache servers to cache values. I want to verify that a specific object gets purged correctly.

My idea was to connect to the right memcache server with telnet and check manually if the key exists.
I know the key that is passed to `Memcache::set`, but not which server to connect to. How do I know on which memcache server the data gets stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just referenced the docs. Memcached clients hash the key to determine which sever to query.  So, I guess Memcached IS sharded.  You will probably have to look at the source of a client (or maybe the docs) to see how the hashing->sever is done.  Otherwise you could just use a client from command line to query for the value.

Comment: Yes, it is sharded, and the hashing is implemented in the PHP extension. It seems like I have to extract the hashing algorithm from the source.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: I wrote a small python script that checks a list of memcache servers for a given key https://gist.github.com/721965

Answer (score -1):

If it's cluster than it's synchronizing data in al instances or have one centralized storage for data (internal realisation - not important for you). You will get data in all instances.